# EditText -Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type int

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-activity

I am new to android programming. And I wanted to set the value of x in edittext and display it on the toast through edittext.The main problem is in x.getText().It gives an error Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type int. plz can anyone help me its an emergency..?

```
Button butt;
EditText edi;
final int x=10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edi=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed);
    final int y = Integer.parseInt(x.getText().toString());
    edi.setText(" "+y);
    butt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
    butt.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String s= edi.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(this, ""+s, 0).show();

}
```

Comment: what is error invoking it?String s= edi.getText().toString();?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: you mean `edi.getText().toString()`

Comment: My que is x.getText() is giving error....how can i take the value of x to pass into editext

Comment: `x` is `int`, is primitive type and doesn't have `getText()`. Did you mean `edi.getText().toString()`?

Comment: If you want to paas the value of x to editText, use edit.setText("" + x);

Comment: no sir....in the line :  final int y = Integer.parseInt(x.getText().toString());  x.getText()

Comment: I don't see what purpose that line is serving. If you want to paas the value of x to editText, remove that line and just use edit.setText("" + x);

Answer (score 2):

try this code:
in oncreate method:

```
    edi=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed);
    final int y = x;
    edi.setText(" "+y);
    butt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
    butt.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The reason for getting error is you are tried to convert the int as int actually the function `Integer.parseInt(String s)` is used to convert the string to int.in your case it is in int type. So that you got an error.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using

```
final int y = Integer.parseInt(edi.getText().toString());
```

instead of

```
final int y = Integer.parseInt(x.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**

```
final int y = Integer.parseInt(x.getText().toString());    // delete this line, getText() is used on objects, to fetch the text from it.
```

**CHANGE THIS**

```
edi.setText(" "+y);
```

**TO**

```
edi.setText(" "+x);
```

Instead of `" " +` , it's good practice to use `String.valueOf(int)`.

```
edi.setText(String.valueOf(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

you got error at this line

```
final int y = Integer.parseInt(x.getText().toString());
```

**because x is Integer** there is no `getText()` method for Integer

you use this

```
edi.setText(" "+x);
final int y = Integer.parseInt(edi.getText().toString());
```

or

```
final int y = x;

edi.setText(" "+y);
```